# Need to add external libraries to GWT project on the server side only

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I am looking to integrate a bunch of external java libraries (jar files) into a GWT project. Note that I do not need them to compile into javascript because they are being called only on the server side. I've copied the files into web-inf/lib but eclipse does not seem to recognize them. I need to call functions in these jar files from the server side only.

Comment: by default the only code that is translated to JavaScript are the ones under the `client` package.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To include external jars in an Eclipse's GWT project you must perform 2 steps:

- Put the files in the WEB-INF/lib directory as you already did
- Include the jars in your Java Build Path in Eclipse.  You will find it in Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path

If you put the jars in the WEB-INF and you call its methods only from the server side, you'll be fine.