# How to create a library and use it in GWT project?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I'm trying to create a UI library to use it in a GWT project named **Test**. This is what I did :

1. Create a new GWT Web Application named **com.example.gwtui.GWTUI**.
2. Create 2 packages : **ui** and **tools**. My UI elements extend GWT elements and are in package ui.
3. Export the project as a jar file named **gwtui.jar**.
4. Configure build path in **Test** and add **gtwui.jar**.
5. Import the package **com.example.gwtui.***. Nothing is underlined in red.
6. Debug **Test** as a web application.
7. It doesn't work. I obtain an error : **The import com.example cannot be resolved** in devmode console.

What did I do wrong ?

Thank you.

Comment: did you add your library to your *.gwt.xml file?

Comment: I just tried to add the following line to my *.gwt.xml file :
    <inherits name='com.example.gwtui.GWTUI'/>
I still have the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to do it, by using Maven.

I created a maven project with the gwt-maven-plugin :

```
Group Id : com.example
Artifact Id : gwtui
Packaging : jar
```

In the pom.xml, I added

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/client/**</include>
            <include>**/*.gwt.xml</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

I built it with maven goal : package.
Then in my Test.gwt.xml, I added

```
<inherits name='com.example.gwtui.GWTUI'/>
```

And I did not forget to add the jar in my build path. And now it works !

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need **to add your jars to Eclipse's GWT project:**

- Put the jar or folder files in the WEB-INF/lib directory
- Include the jars in your Java Build Path in Eclipse.You will find it in Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path

See also:
[Need to add external libraries to GWT project on the server side only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12751783/need-to-add-external-libraries-to-gwt-project-on-the-server-side-only)

Comment: Hello. I did what you say and I still have this error.